# Generate line chart from SQL database output using Morris

Tags: javascript, php

```
<script>
<?php
unset($data0);
unset($data1);
unset($data2);

$sth = $dbh->prepare("
SELECT a, b, c
FROM   t
");
$sth->execute();
?>

Morris.Line({
  element: 'morris-line-chart',
  data: [
  <?php
  while ($row = $sth->fetch()) { ?>
    { m: '<?php echo $row['0']; ?>', a: <?php echo $row['1']; ?>, b: <?php echo $row['2']; ?> },
  <?php } ?>
  ],
  xkey: 'm',
  xLabels: 'month',
  ykeys: ['a', 'b'],
  labels: ['2014', '2015']
});
</script>
```

Is there a cleaner way to write it, especially the PHP echoing to create the JavaScript?

Answer (score 3):

I like to keep the Javascript in one echo at the bottom, like this:

```
<?php

unset($data0);
unset($data1);
unset($data2);

$sth = $dbh->prepare("SELECT a, b, c FROM t");
$sth->execute();

$data = '';
while ($row = $sth->fetch(FETCH_ASSOC)) { 
  extract($row);
  $data .= "{ m: '$c', a: $a, b: $b },".PHP_EOL;
} 

echo "<script>
Morris.Line({
  element: 'morris-line-chart',
  data: [$data],
  xkey: 'm',
  xLabels: 'month',
  ykeys: ['a', 'b'],
  labels: ['2014', '2015']
});
</script>";
```

I had to make the assumptions that you're using PDO and that `$c` is your `m` in the morris line.